# read and get data from xml file stored in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hi everybody I am new with AWS Lambda Function i have to work with python.
I want to read an xml file stored in a S3 Bucket and get the data from the xml file with python and save it in a json variable.
Does anybody knows a library or a lambda function that do this?-
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmltodict` library in python. It will be good if you first do bit of search on this as well.

Basic idea to use `xmltodict` as first you can read xml and convert it to dictionary and then to json object.

```
import json
import xmltodict
with open("test.xml") as xml_file:
     
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
```

**Note:** Assuming you can read file from S3 bucket with boto3

Comment: I actually found xmltodict library but I was having the next error: "errorMessage": "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict". I asket after looking for some other libraries